# Query to convert from MB into a GB value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get results from a query that gives me the result from the column Filesize. That value from Filesize was converted at the begging to a MB value and now I want do do a query that convert that value into a GB value. This is the query that I am using right now

```
SELECT 
CAST(SUM(Filesize) / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) 
FROM infofile
```

If you could help I would appreciate it

If I use the query

```
SELECT 
    SUM(FILESIZE)
    FROM infofile
```

the value that I will get it '1326278' and if I divide it by 1024 gives me 1295(MB) and I want to get it in GB and it will gives me with this query

```
    SELECT 
CAST(SUM(Filesize) / 1024 / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM infofile
```

1.00

Comment: What type of DB is it?

Comment: This is such a simple math operation... *hint* divide again or double 1024.

Comment: Help with what?  Your math looks right - what problem are you having?

Comment: The query that you are using now is essentially the answer...

Comment: @t0mm13b dividing again is correct - doubling 1024 is incorrect example : 
(9/3)/3 is 1 (9/6) is 1.5

Comment: @Chris double 1024, use that to divide. :)

Comment: @t0mm13b doubling 1024 gives 2048 -  you mean square :)

Comment: @Chris whooops... soz, I stand corrected... /scurries off to write double 1024 is not same as square 1000 times on blackboard... :)

Comment: @t0mm13b could you help me if I want to get the result of my query like 1.265 instead 1.00

Comment: @Forrobodo give an example number that is given from Sum(Filesize)

Comment: I will edit the question @t0mm13b

Comment: What is the datatype of `Filesize`?

Comment: It's int @TabAlleman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query will give you the size in GB :-

```
select CAST(SUM(cast(Filesize as float)) / 1024 / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```

Try now it will give the required result.

Comment: I have tried it at the beginning. But it will gives me 1.00 and I've used a convert program and it will gives me 1.26. How can I get that?

Comment: I have done the modification in the query as per the requirement , try now.

Comment: It will shows me a message 'Invalid column name 'Filesize'.'

Comment: @Forrobodo you need to replace 'Filesize' with the column in your query that contains the megabyte value you want to convert to gigabytes.

Answer (score 2):

To get Gigabytes, divide it again by 1024.

```
SELECT 
CAST((SUM(Filesize) / 1024) / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) 
FROM infofile
```

Or, multiply 1024 * 1024 = 1048576

So the expression would be:

```
SELECT 
CAST(SUM(Filesize) / 1048576 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) 
FROM infofile
```

Comment: The value that I'm getting with it is 1.00 and I wanna get the exact value you know?

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact vales after decimal point, you should multiply the filesize with 1.0

```
SELECT 
CAST((SUM(Filesize)*1.0 / 1024) / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) 
FROM infofile
```